# How to organise relationships between Django model?

Tags: django

I have basic Django User model,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Person model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and Comment model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I wanna make something like: I created User, I has own unique id ( for example 1). I created Person, I has own unique id and link to User. And then I created Comment - it has link to Person model. I want that one User can have many Persons. One Person can have Comments

Comment: To define a many-to-one relationship, use ForeignKey which you already did !!

Comment: This code looks fine can you tell what error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the `Comment` as a different model? If not, I would use create a comment field inside the `Person` class, and I would use `views.py` to add comments in the `Person.comment` field.

Also, the inquiry you are describing is actually solved since you use the many-to-one relationship by using the `ForeignKey` in your classes

Comment: What if I need to store multiple comments to Person?

Comment: wel then, the Comment class would be necessary, but as I said, and based on the comment in your question by Vishal Pandey, since you have a ForeignKey it would work